# Some problem similar to Dido's problem

Tags: differential-geometry

The question is :
"Let $A$ and $B$ be two fixed points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Given $L>$ length of $AB$. Show that the curve $\alpha$ joining A and B, with length $L$, which together with *AB* forms a Jordan curve (i.e. a simple closed curve), bounds the largest possible area is an arc of a circle passing through $A$ and $B$."
This is an homework question from a Differential Geometry Course.
It seems that it is related to isoperimetric inequality but I don't have any idea to prove it.

Comment: Is the proof of the isoperimetric inequality covered in your class?  Are you expected to imitate that proof in your exercise?

Comment: Yes, the lecturer use a theorem in Fourier analysis.It required the boundary is smooth.

Comment: It makes sense that in a course on Differential Geometry you would assume smoothness of the curve $\alpha$.  I think $\mathscr{C}^1$ smoothness is sufficient here.